# Grouping of Data in UI5 XML Table

Tags: sapui5

I have a xml table listing Product ID and the status from the odata consumed. I have grouped the data(PFA) based on the concept of sorting and filtering. 
I want to further group the Product ID with repetitive occurrence in the xml table and show the count of the grouped products.

Note: In my table I have a product called "Power Wheel Chair" with three occurrence. I want to group it as display only one power wheel chair with the count as 3 in another field.

Please provide your suggestions on how to accomplish this. Also do revert back for further queries.[Grouping table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vhom.png)

Regards,
Srinivasan

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to have the server to handle aggregation of lines items into totals and have it to return the condensed set in a separate EntitySet (e.g. `ProductCounts`), that would look something like this:

```
[ 
    { product: A, count: 5 },
    { product: B, count: 7 } 
]
```

Doing this on the server, has the benefit that a much smaller set of data is downloaded to the client. In the earlier example 12 records would have been downloaded instead of two. On top of that, the client doensn't need to do the processing and math, but this is delegated to the server. And that's great, because the server usually has the means to crunch large amounts of data efficiently.

If you still want to do the calculation client side, I would suggest writing a little code in the success handler of the ODataModel.read method that does the aggregation and pushes the result into a JSON model. You can then bind the JSON model to your table control.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I am new to UI5. Can you provide any code samples if possible. It would help me a lot

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it would help you if someone else writes your code. But sorry, it's not right to ask someone to write your code on Stackoverflow (try freelancer.com instead). The answer above is quite elaborate and goes into pros and cons of the various solutions. Now it's up to you to define your solution strategy, write your own code, and learn Javascript and UI5 along that way.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will look into it for my solution.